# Recorrer lista en orden inverso en haskell con recursión

Tags: haskell

Hola tengo que hacer este ejercicio:

Definir la función

```
largoCola :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Int
```

que determina cuantos elementos cumplen con un predicado, pero desde la cola de la lista hacia la cabeza. O sea, de fin a principio.

No estoy encontrando la forma de hacerlo. Muchas gracias, saludos.

Answer (score 2):

La implementación podría ser asi:

```hs
largoCola :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Int 
largoCola f [] = 0
largoCola f (x:xs) | f x = 1 + largoCola f xs
                   | otherwise = largoCola f xs
```

Aunque parezca que el cálculo va del primero al último, hace primero el cálculo con la cola de la lista. Si lo analizas, va desde el último al primero.

Este tipo de procesamiento, de derecha a izquierda, se conoce como `foldr` (*doblado desde la derecha*). Se podría hacer mejor así:

```hs
largoCola :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Int 
largoCola f = foldr g 0
  where g x acc = acc + if f x then 1 else 0
```